# Correct preposition for “payment method”

Tags: prepositions

> I bought a car with payment that will be made starting from March to June.

Would ''with'' be better in this sentence and grammatically correct?

Comment: The difficulty is that you didn't but a car with "payment" but with "money"

Comment: I thought that by using “with” I can describe how I will make the payment. Is the sentence totally unclear with “with”?

Comment: I suppose you can use "payment", but it is somewhat figurative.  Perhaps "payments" would have been better.

Comment: Buying a car on credit is widely known as **hire purchase**. So you bought a car on/through hire purchase (often shortened to **hp**) with the first instalment/payment starting/due in March. (rather than March to June).

Comment: I bought a car and my [loan] payments will start in X.

Comment: @RonaldSole **hire purchase** must be a Commonwealth usage; I've never heard it in the US and wouldn't have understood it out of context.  In the US I guess we'd just say we got a loan to buy the car.

Comment: hire purchase in American English is to lease a car. You are renting it until you pay it off.

Comment: Better than what? You already have "with" in the sentence. What are you comparing it to?

Comment: @Lambie Car leases in the US usually don't end with you owning the car, unless you have a specific buyout agreement.  If you're paying it off over time, then you're just financing it.

Comment: Yes, you can lease to own in the States. https://www.chase.com/personal/auto/education/leasing/lease-to-own-car